# jQuery UI datepicker get today's date or previous date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker, I'm trying to show an alert when the user clicks on today's date or any previous date before today's date, but I don't know how, I managed to retrieve each date onchange but I can't do the rest, here is my jQuery code for selecting today's date:

```
$(document).on("change", "#datepicker", function () {
    alert($(this).val())
})
```

Comment: you'll have to use javascript's date() functions, then compare that value you got to that or dates less than today's or previous date

Comment: @j08691 thanks for the sarcasm :)

Comment: @clearshot66 well, before you changed your comment from "You'll need JavaScript" it was more fitting

Answer (score 1):

```
    This code find currrent date and if block compare the selected date is current date or not and then prompt alert!

     <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
 var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate();
var mnth = today.getMonth()+1; 

var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(date<10){
    date='0'+date;
} 
if(mnth<10){
    mnth='0'+mnth;
} 
var today = mnth+'/'+date+'/'+yyyy;
alert(today); // Display current date


  $(document).on("change", "#datepicker", function () {
         if($(this).val()<=today)
         {
         alert($(this).val())
         }
    });

  } );


  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to retrieve today's date onclick not on load, and this code retrieves dates after today's date, i only want previous dates

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get selected date using [`getDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) method and comparing it with current time. You can use JavaScript Date [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) to get:

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date.

Here a working sample:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker();

$(document).on("change", "#datepicker", function () {
  // Get datepicker value
  var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker( "getDate" );
  // Get current time
  var today = new Date().valueOf();
  // Compare current time and selected date
  if( selectedDate && selectedDate.valueOf() < today ){
    alert('You selected a past date: ' + $(this).val())
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```